# Can migration to magento2 break live magento1 site?

Tags: magento2, migration

We plan on migrating soon and I want to try out the migration tool. It worked fine with a dump of our live website db, but that's bad practice since delta won't work this way.

Can the migration process affect our live magento1 website in anyway ? Does it have any chance of breaking it ? Do we NEED to put the website in maintenance mode before doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is absolutely no when you use a reliable automated migration tool. It helps to migrate all data from your old platform to another one without interrupting your current store performance so your store still runs normally and you still receive new customers and orders.

After that, choose Recent Data Migration or Smart Update to move the recent data to the new store.